# How to determine if the user searched in a sublocality, locality, state etc in google maps api for react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

I am setting up a location service where users can search for places (e.g hospitals, train stations etc) in a certain area. **I want to know if there is a way to determine the granularity of the user's query i.e. if the user searched in a sublocality, locality, state or an entire country. Is there any API that can give me the break down of the query?**

Currently, I am using the textSearch api in google.maps.places.PlacesService for getting results from the google maps API. This can return upto 60 results. I then take one of the result's place_id and use the getDetails API to get detailed information about the place. But this only breaks down the address components of the retrieved results. **I would like to get the break down of the query.**

```js
let placesSearchBoxService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
placesSearchBoxService.textSearch(request, (res, status, pag) => {
    // SEARCH UNSUCCESSFUL
    if (status !== 'OK') {
        return;
    }
    let detailRequest = { placeId: res[0].place_id };
    placesSearchBoxService.getDetails(detailRequest, (place, status) => {
        let { address_components: addressComponents } = place;
    ...
    });
});
```